# Change Pointer Style with CSS

Tags: css

Is there we can make the pointer blink "vertically" with CSS, Example ( _ ), Can we change the Pointer form " | " to " ___ " . Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the following CSS rule, on the element you want to target:

```css
cursor: vertical-text;
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Comment: Actually the default courser need to be vertically blinking ( __ )

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the cursor between two cursor types with a timer

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var myElement = document.getElementById("myElement")

    if(myElement.style.cursor == "vertical-text")
        myElement.style.cursor = "none";
    else
        myElement.style.cursor = "vertical-text";
}, 1000);
```